# validation error due to "nil" objects when values are passed with --set in HELM

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to pass a value using the `--set` in `helm3`. However, it looks like the yaml file is not pulling/parsing the value.

My folder structure is like below: (there are a few other charts but I have removed them for simplicity)

```
k8shelmcharts
├── Chart.yaml
└── charts
    ├── postgresdb
    │   ├── Chart.yaml
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   ├── postgres.configmap.yml
    │   │   ├── postgres.deployment.yml
    │   │   ├── postgres.secrets.yml
    │   │   └── postgres.service.yml
    │   └── values.yaml
```

and the contents of the `postgres.secrest.yml` file is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postgres-secret
  type: Opaque
data:
  # property-like keys; each key maps to a simple value
  password: {{ .Values.password }}
```

( I have also tried `.Values.global.password` )

When I try to install the charts by running the command (from the root of the helm charts ie: `k8shelmcharts` folder) `helm install testapp . --set password=postgrespasssword --debug --dry-run`

I get the error:

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: unknown object type "nil" in Secret.data.password
helm.go:94: [debug] error validating "": error validating data: unknown object type "nil" in Secret.data.password
```

If I try to generate the templates using `helm template testflaskapp . --set password=postgrespassword --debug --dry-run`, I can see that the password does not seem to get populated in the `postgres.secret.yml` file -

```
# Source: flask-k8s-app/charts/postgresdb/templates/postgres.secret.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postgres-secret
data:
  # property-like keys; each key maps to a simple value
  password:
```

Any help on what I am missing so that I can `--set` values and pull them in the yaml files successfully? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```sh
helm install testapp . --set postgresdb.password=postgrespasssword --debug --dry-run
```

The variable should be called `postgresdb.password`, in the postgres.secrets.yml should stay `{{ .Values.password }}`.

**Option 2**

```sh
helm install testapp . --set global.password=postgrespasssword --debug --dry-run
```

The variable should be called `global.password`, postgres.secrets.yml should be changed to `{{ .Values.global.password }}`.

The first option is the preferable one I guess, as probably you are using the postgress password only in the `postgresdb` subchart.

Reference: [Subcharts and Global Values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/)